# AlertView ClickedButtonAtIndex not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I've read the related posts but must be missing something since my ClickedButtonAtIndex method is not being called after hitting the OK button on my alert.  I set a breakpoint within the ClickedButtonAtIndex method, it is never reached and the NSLog is never executed.

Here's the .h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainPage : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *sendtxtlabel;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here is the .m code here:

```
@interface MainPage ()

@end

@implementation MainPage

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sendtxtlabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number 800-555-1212"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Vehicle Owner"
                          message:@"Enter Phone Number"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    alert.tag =12;
    //[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"ok"];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"ok");


}



- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Capture the phone number input from the alert pop-up window. UIAlertView Delegate added to allow the OS trigger this method to read the data.

    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"phonenumber: %@", textfield.text);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Case matters in the name of the delegate method. You have alertview instead of alertView.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thx!

Comment: My next question is how to use this text in another method in the same .m file.  I want to use the phone number contained in textfield.txt in another method.  (perhaps this should be posted as a separate question?)